# Как нарисовать одну картинку из ресурсов Android приложения несколько раз?

Tags: android, android-studio, графика

Есть картинка, хранящаяся в /res/drawable/ .Как можно нарисовать ее несколько раз в зависимости от определенной переменной.Допустим переменная = 5, то мы рисуем ее 5 раз.На экране это выглядит как несколько картинок стоящих друг за другом.

Comment: Решил вопрос с помошью создания ImageView в цикле и установки на них Drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно либо изначально заготовить нужное количество ImageView в вашем layout а потом для каждой присваивать ресурс картинки таким образом

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_imageView);
 imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat. getDrawable (this, R.drawable.yourImage));
```

Либо создавать imageView динамически типа

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);
image  imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat. getDrawable (this, R.drawable.yourImage));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать любой список, где ваша переменная будет являться его размером.